# Make elements visible in HTML in a Django project

Tags: javascript, python, django-templates

I come to seek your help in a Django web project. I have a sidebar that displays various options, and I need two button groups to become visible when clicking on the following element:

Tipo de persona

I created a JavaScript script to achieve this functionality, but the button groups still do not become visible on the page. If someone could assist me, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
<ul class="nav child_menu">
    {% if user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'direccion' or user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'admin' %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_sucursales' %}">Establecimientos</a></li>                          
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_tipos_persona' %}" id="tipo-persona-link">Tipo de persona</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_generos' %}">Genero persona</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_personas' %}">Persona</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_alumnos' %}">Alumno</a></li>
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'convivencia escolar' or user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'direccion' or user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'inspectoria' or user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'admin' %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_cursos' %}">Curso</a></li>
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
</ul>

<div id="botoneras" style="display: none;">
    <!-- Botonera Content -->
    <button>Apoderado</button>
    <button>Docente</button>
</div>`

<script>
    // Get the "Tipo de persona" link
    const tipoPersonaLink = document.getElementById("tipo-persona-link");

    // Add a click event to the "Tipo de persona" link
    tipoPersonaLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default navigation behavior

        // Show or hide the button groups
        const botoneras = document.getElementById("botoneras");
        if (botoneras.style.display === "none") {
            botoneras.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            botoneras.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just copy-pasted your code into a snippet, and it works.
Please let me know if the behavior in the snippet is not what you expected, and I will change the answer to help you.

I had to cut unrelated list items to make `tipo-persona-link` and buttons fit the snippet demo window.

```html
<ul class="nav child_menu">
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_tipos_persona' %}" id="tipo-persona-link">Tipo de persona</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="botoneras" style="display: none;">
    <!-- Botonera Content -->
    <button>Apoderado</button>
    <button>Docente</button>
</div>`

<script>
    // Get the "Tipo de persona" link
    const tipoPersonaLink = document.getElementById("tipo-persona-link");

    // Add a click event to the "Tipo de persona" link
    tipoPersonaLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default navigation behavior

        // Show or hide the button groups
        const botoneras = document.getElementById("botoneras");
        if (botoneras.style.display === "none") {
            botoneras.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            botoneras.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
</script>
```